# Can every convergence be expressed as convergence in a topological space?

Tags: general-topology, recreational-mathematics

Given a set $X$, let's call a relation $\longrightarrow \subseteq X^{\mathbb{N}} \times X$ **convergence**, if the following hold:

1. Every constant sequence converges to the constant, i.e. $$(x, x, \dots) \longrightarrow x \quad \forall x \in X$$
2. If a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to some $x$, i.e. $(x_n)_n \longrightarrow x$, then so does every subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$, i.e. $(x_{n_k})_k \longrightarrow x$.

If further limits are unique, i.e. $(x_n)_n \longrightarrow x \wedge (x_n)_n \longrightarrow y \implies x = y$, the convergence is called **unique**.

Now, I am interested in the following question in the unique and the non-unique case:

> Given a convergence $\longrightarrow$, is there always a topology
>   $\mathcal{O}$ on $X$ such that $$s \longrightarrow x \iff \text{$s$
>  converges to $x$ in the topological space $(X, \mathcal{O})$}$$ i.e.,
>   $\longrightarrow$ can be expressed as topological convergence?

This is just for fun, but I have little experience in topology and only managed to show (I think :)) that the answer is no if condition 1 is omitted.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5537/notions-of-convergence-not-corresponding-to-topologies
This might be interesting for you!

Comment: You do need more: see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137596/can-we-define-the-concept-of-limit-without-a-topology/1137774#1137774) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19681/when-is-a-notion-of-convergence-induced-by-a-topology/37643#37643) (linked from the first), and perhaps [this page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subsequential+space) at nLab.