# Deriving topology from sequence convergence/limits?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

Normally convergence of a series and the limit of a convergent series are defined relative to a topology. That is, you start with a topology, and then you define a series as convergent based on that topology, using the well known definition:

> A series $(a_n)$ converges to $a$ if for every neighbourhood $N$ of $a$ there's an $m\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n>m$, $a_n\in N$.

Now I'm thinking about whether it is possible to reverse that process: Start with a declaration which series are divergent, and what is the limit of all convergent series, and then use that to define a topology, by simply reversing the above definition:

> A set $N$ is a neighbourhood of a point $a$ if for every series $(a_n)$ converging to $a$ there exists an $m\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n>m$, $a_n\in N$.

More formally, a limit function for a set $M$ would be defined as a function
$$ l: \mathbb N^M \to M\cup \{\text{divergent}\}$$
mapping all sequences of values in $M$ either to a value in $M$ (saying that the value converges to that value) or to the special value $\text{divergent}\notin M$ (saying that the sequence is divergent, of course). That function, to be considered a limit, would of course have to fulfil some requirements to count as limit functions. I think an obvious set of conditions would be:

- For the constant sequence $(a) = (a,a,a,a,a,\ldots)$, $l((a)) = a$.
- If $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ differ in only finitely many terms, then $l((a_n))=l((b_n))$.
- If $(b_n)$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)$ and $(a_n)$ converges, then $l((b_n)) = l((a_n))$.
- If $c_n$ is obtained by interleaving $a_n$ and $b_n$ (where the interleaving may be in any possible way) then
  $$l((c_n)) = \begin{cases}l((a_n)) & \text{if } l((a_n))=l((b_n))\\
  \text{divergent} & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Of course what remains to be shown is whether the definition above indeed results in a neighbourhood topology. Looking at the [axioms given on Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Neighbourhoods_definition) all but one are easily proved. The one I don't see how to prove is the last one:

> Any neighbourhood N of x contains a neighbourhood M of x such that N is a neighbourhood of each point of M.

Therefore my question is:

**Does the above neighbourhood definition together with the "limit axioms" I've given above define a topology? And if not, is there some additional property of limits I've missed, adding of which to the list would be sufficient to make it a topology?**

Comment: I rather suspect your missing axiom here describes reflexivity of the closeness relation. And I think that is hidden within your "where interleaving may be in any possible way" statement because exchanging the interleaving of any two subsequences is only possible if closeness is reflexive.

Comment: In case it is interesting for you, this answer of mine contains a reference to a way how to get topology from convergence sequences: [When is a notion of convergence induced by a topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/19681#37643)

Comment: It seems like the concept of sequential spaces answers this question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space Or is there a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a simpler approach would be to define $N$ is closed if every convergent sequence in $N$ has its limit in $N$. This should be equivalent to your definition. It is obvious that the entire space and the empty set are both closed, And not much harder to see that the intersection of any collection of closed sets is also closed. The final condition - that a finite union of closed sets is closed - takes a bit more work, but follows from the fact that any convergent sequence in the union must have a convergent subsequence in one of the sets.

Of all your conditions, the only one that is necessary is that every subsequence of a convergent sequence converges to the same limit. The other conditions just express additional details about the topology.

Comment: This always defines a topology, but it may not define a topology for which convergence of sequences is given by the function $l$ (there may be more convergent sequences).

Comment: I believe this is the coarsest topology in which every $l$-convergent sequence also converges in the topology. If there are more sequences that converge, then this indicates a weakness in $l$. So perhaps the interesting question becomes, what is the weakest set of additional conditions on $l$ so that convergence in this induced topology is equivalent to $l$-convergence?

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Do you mean "the *finest* topology in which ..."? The coarsest topology (at all) is the trivial (indiscrete) topology, and in it, all sequences converge to all points.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I was reading a recent algebraic geometry thread about affine schemes here https://twitter.com/SC_Griffith/status/1291496000293675009 and the same or similar technique was used; namely to consider level sets closed if they include their limit points. One day I hope to understand why this makes sense. It also mentioned the famous Zariski topology. Sadly I couldn't make head nor tail of that!

Comment: @samerivertwice - really? You were reading about algebraic geometry on a twitter thread about defunding the police?

Comment: @PaulSinclair can you please double-check that? She's an algebraic geometer. I think she just happens to have changed her username to say defund the police to make some political statement. But unless I'm seeing something different to you it's a thread about a related topological subject.

Comment: @samerivertwice - my apologies. As for defining closed sets by defining limits, what doesn't make sense? "Contains all its limit points" is the very idea of being "closed". Being the complement of an open set is just an easy equivalent property.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I suspect topology is a subject where you have to have that penny dropping moment where suddenly it all makes sense and that hasn't happened for me yet. It may just be happening as I'm starting to see how the definition of Cauchy sequences is intertwined with open and closedness.