# Fréchet L-Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, reference-request, convergence-divergence, math-history

NOTE: The question has now been posted on MathOverflow: [Fréchet L-Spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/q/237344)

According to the paper [The emergence of open sets, closed sets, and limit points
in analysis and topology](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.hm.2008.01.001)   famous mathematician [Maurice Fréchet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurice_Ren%C3%A9_Fr%C3%A9chet) who introduced the concept of metric spaces has also introduced another similar class of abstract spaces  called **Limit spaces** based on the primitive idea of the limit of an infinite sequence in 1904, which was defined as follows:

> An L-space is a set $X$ together with a function $F : S\to X,$ where $S$ is a set of infinite sequences of members of $X$.
>   If $(x_n)\in S$, then $F(x_n)$ was said to be the *“limit of the sequence $(x_n)$"* satisfying following two axioms:
>
> $A_1$: If $(x_n)$ is a constant sequence whose value is $a$, then $F(x_n)=a$.
>
> $A_2$: If $F(x_n)=a$, then for any sub-sequence of $(x_n)$ given by $(x_{n_k})$ we have $F(x_{n_k})=a$.

I would like to know more about mathematics on L-spaces. But I could not find any thing by Googling.
Where could I find about these spaces?
Also I wonder; why this concept is not popular in mathematics?

Comment: Look for convergence spaces. These are a generalisation of topological spaces in a similar way. The difference is that filters and their convergence is used for definition instead of the convergence of sequences.

Comment: Have you tried looking in Kelley's book? https://archive.org/details/GeneralTopology

Comment: See: last chapter of [**Set Topology**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0486404560) by Vaidyanathaswamy; *History of Sequential Convergence Spaces* in [**Handbook of the History of General Topology, Volume I**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0792344790); Angus Ellis Taylor's lengthy (217 pages in three parts) historical analysis of Frechet's work (see my answer [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119829/what-are-normal-sets-fr%C3%A9chet)); Richard Friederich Arens, [*Note on convergence in topology*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3028991),
**Mathematics Magazine** 23 #5 (May-June 1950), 229-234.

Comment: If anyone is interested, I looked through my copy of Kelley's book this morning and all I found was net and filter convergence -- nothing about Fréchet's $L$-spaces (in fact, nothing about notions that are closely related to $L$-spaces by Fréchet or by other people).

Comment: See also the structure of uniform space https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space developed in Bourbaki.

Comment: Now posted also on MathOverflow: [Fréchet L-Spaces](http://mathoverflow.net/q/237344)

Comment: You might be interested in Problems 1.7.18-1.7.20 in Engelking's book and references listed there. You can look also at [my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19681/when-is-a-notion-of-convergence-induced-by-a-topology/37643#37643). And of course, it might be reasonable to try to have a look at papers which [cite the original Frechet's paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=1803710952850005944).